# breaking infinite loop / proper loop setting

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, do-while

In my application I have a mysql db table with many numerical records. I am doing some computations to these records. I would like to perform this computation in a loop with a ending condition. I was thinking about do-while loop, but I have scenario like this:

```
LOOP: {
    LOOP for computing euklidian distances between chosen records
    // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHCECK IF MY ENDING CONDITION IS TRUE. 
    // IF YES, WHOLE LOOP WILL END, AND IF NO, IT WILL CONTINUE
    LOOP for updating table records according to euklidian distances.
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true)
{
  // some code

  if (condition)
    break; // HERE

  // some other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve that with a simple endless loop and `break`:

```
while (true)
{
    // do computation
    if (/* check condition */)
        break;
    // update DB
}
```

Then the loop will run until the condition is met. You may should also ensure that this will not turn into an endless loop...

Answer (score 0):

"Foreach" loop may be better for you to use for computing for each record from the table.

```
foreach(var record in listOfRecords)
{
    //LOOP for computing euklidian distances between chosen records

    if(condition)
    {
        break;
    }

    //LOOP for updating table records according to euklidian distances.
}
```